# JQuery data is not "bind" with click submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, data-binding

i have a tip game where are many games on a list. If you click on a game´s quote, a modal opens with the data and you can set your amount and then with submit you can submit it via ajax. I don´t know whats going wrong, but since 2 days i have a binding problem.
When i click on some quotes and then I take an amount.. then it submits not only one, it submits all i have clicked before...

that´s crazy.. here is my js code

```
    $('.ui.buttons').on('click', 'a.quote.button', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // FOR DESKTOP
        // $('#bet').fadeIn(300);


        var id = $(this).data('id');
        var tip = $(this).data('tip');
        var game = $(this).data('game');
        var team = $(this).data('team');
        var quote = $(this).data('quote');
        var earnings = 0;
        var amount = $('#stake').val();
        console.log(game);
        $('#game').text(game);
        $('#team').text(team);
        $('#tip').text(tip);
        $('#quote').text(quote);

        bet.modal('show');

        //bet.on('change', '#submit', function(){
        //   console.log(2);
        $("#submit").bind('click', function (ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            $(this).unbind(ev);
            var game = {};
            game.id = id;
            game.tip = tip;
            game.quote = quote;
            game.amount = $('#stake').val();

    //SEND TIP
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url + '/bet',
        data: {game_id: game.id, tip: game.tip, quote: game.quote, stake: game.amount}, .....
        });
```

Comment: an you try `e.stopPropagation();` and `ev.stopPropagation();` ?

Comment: Your code is missing a `});`

Comment: Because you keep binding to the submit button on every click.

Comment: What does the click on submit do? Is the `.bind()` functon inside the `.on()` ?? Correct your code please

Comment: no the #submit isn´t inside the .on() you mean that´s the error? Aramil?

Comment: @epascarello where is it missing? after this there comes a closing }); from the .on()

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I have closed it before the #submit binds.

```
$('body').on('click', 'a.quote.button', function (e) {
//  e.stopPropagation();
$('a.button.active').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
// FOR DESKTOP
// $('#bet').fadeIn(300);


id = $(this).data('id');
tip = $(this).data('tip');
game = $(this).data('game');
team = $(this).data('team');
quote = $(this).data('quote');
earnings = 0;
amount = $('#stake').val();
console.log(game);
$('#game').text(game);
$('#team').text(team);
$('#tip').text(tip);
$('#quote').text(quote);

bet.modal('show');

earnings = quote * amount;

return false;
});

  $("#submit").on('click', function () {
   ....
   });
```